# App Store offers Safari 11.0.2 which I already have

Tags: safari, mac-appstore

Today App Store offered me Safari 11.0.2. But I already have this. See the screenshot below.

Should I just update it again? Or is there something else I can do?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes install it.

It's an updated version released today that has fixes for the Spectre bug that's in the news.

More information here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208403

Comment: Odd they didn't give it a new number, even if just another .x.x.1

Comment: It's strikes me as odd too. But they've done that before. I don't really understand why, but it's definitely not the first time they've released an update without bumping the version number.

Comment: i just got same offer for Sierra 10.13.2 which is what I am running now.